# Right to left (RTL) Electronic program guid (EPG) in Android

Tags: android, android-view

I want to create an **Electronic program guid** or **EPG**, that scrolls both horizontal, vertical and diagonal (Listed on `Y-axis` are channels and `X-axis` are programs/events).

I found a [library](https://github.com/korre/android-tv-epg/blob/master/app/src/main/java/se/kmdev/tvepg/epg/EPG.java) which is exactly what I want. My app support multi language so I want to support RTL language. But as I see source code it's calculate position and based on that call `onDraw()` I want to know does exist any way to make this View RTL?

**Last try**: set `layoutDirection` but not worked.

Answer (score 0):

add this to your AndroidManifest.xml:

```
<application 
...
android:supportsRtl="true"
>
```

As View checks RTL support first, if true, then resolve layout direction.

You can get more details in View.resolveLayoutDirection().

Comment: Thanks But Not working. As I mentioned in question setLayoutDirection not working because it's draw Views based on x/y position.

Comment: may be draw view does't suppot RTL features.

Comment: off-course it doesn't, And my question is How make this customView RTL :)

Comment: try to draw view in java script and load the webview